# wordpress, how to change contents of only the first post in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
<?php 
    $freeadvice=new WP_Query('category_name=freeadvice&showposts=10');
    while($freeadvice->have_posts() ): $freeadvice->the_post();
?>
    <li class="event">
        <input type="radio" name="tl-group" />
        ....
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

This is my current code for my loop, but what i am trying to create that in first post, that is the recent one post should have the first line of the inner list item as

```
<input type="radio" name="tl-group" checked/>
```

now every time i add a new post i need the first child to be added with this attribute, is this possible using php or may be javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a flag

```
<?php 
    $flag = true;
    $freeadvice=new WP_Query('category_name=freeadvice&showposts=10');
    while($freeadvice->have_posts() ): $freeadvice->the_post();
?>
    <li class="event">
  <input type="radio" name="tl-group" <?php if ($flag) { echo "checked"; $flag = false; } ?>/>
        ....
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Yeah, i was doing that but it says cant mark before 4 minutes , thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

As for what i understood, u want the radio button present in the first Li item to have the attribute as checked. am i right?

What i would do is initialize a variable with zero just before the while loop and only for the first instance i would provide the checked attribute. for remaining all i wont. Example:

```
<?php 
    $freeadvice=new WP_Query('category_name=freeadvice&showposts=10');\
    $x=0; //initializing variable
    while($freeadvice->have_posts() ): $freeadvice->the_post();
        if($x==0) //If block is executed only for the first instance
        {
?>
            <li class="event">
                <input type="radio" name="tl-group" checked/> //providing checked attribute
                ....
            </li>
    <?php
        }else{ //else block is executed for all other instances
    ?>
            <li class="event">
                <input type="radio" name="tl-group" />
                ....
            </li>
    <?php
        }
        $x=$x+1; //incrementing x value
    ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

So in this way only when `$x` variable is 0, that is only for the first time, the if block is executed and the radio button will get the attribute `checked`. then the `$x` is incremented and every other time the else block is executed.

It is important to declare `$x` as 0 every time before starting the while loop. hence the initialization just before while loop.

Hope it helps..

Comment: A very efficient code is given by zoranc. this is just a lengthy procedure but easy to understand.